# Use rack aware policy for kafka in apache storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

We need to implement a rack awareness feature for Kafka using storm spout. For this, we need to set property **cleint.rack** with availability zone as value from the node where this topology is running. But it is giving me the availability zone of the master nimbus node. How can I get the actual host availability zone value for the node on which the spout is running for this topology?

In short, how can I provide the availability zone of the host node where the spout is running during the configuration of KafkaSpout before the stormCluster.submit call.

KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> userCardIndexKafkaSpoutConfig =
KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(
userCardIndexSpoutInputKafkaBroker, userCardIndexSpoutInputKafkaTopic)
.setProp("group.id", userCardIndexSpoutInputKafkaConsumerGroup)
.setProp("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class)
.setProp("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class)
.setProp("client.rack",availabilityZone)
.setProcessingGuarantee(KafkaSpoutConfig.ProcessingGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
.setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(FirstPollOffsetStrategy.UNCOMMITTED_EARLIEST)
.setMaxUncommittedOffsets(1)
.setProp(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 500)
.setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(200)
.build();
KafkaSpout<String, String> userCardIndexKafkaSpout =
new KafkaSpout<>(userCardIndexKafkaSpoutConfig);